# VTD-XML : XMLModifier.output() throws an IndexOutOfBoundsException

Tags: java, xml, xml-parsing, vtd-xml, xml-encoding

I have been to trying to modify a xml file using VTD-XML.The xml has been received from a java (JAX-WS) web service as a String. The http response header from the server has **content type : text/xml** and **charset = utf-8**.

Here is the code :

```
private static byte[] getDataFromFile(String filePath) throws IOException {
    File file = new File(filePath);
    FileInputStream fileInputStream = new FileInputStream(file);
    byte[] byteArray = new byte[(int) file.length()];
    fileInputStream.read(byteArray);
    String fileData = new String(byteArray);
    byteArray = fileData.getBytes("UTF-16");
    return byteArray;
}

private static void cutOffXmlByXpath(String xpathQuery, String inputFilePath, String outputFilePath) throws Exception {
    byte[] byteArray = getDataFromFile(inputFilePath);

    VTDGen vg = new VTDGen();
    vg.setDoc(byteArray);
    vg.parse(false);
    VTDNav vn = vg.getNav();

    AutoPilot ap = new AutoPilot(vn);
    ap.selectXPath(xpathQuery);

    XMLModifier xm = new XMLModifier(vn);

    while((ap.evalXPath())!=-1) {
        xm.remove(vn.getElementFragment());
    }

    xm.output(outputFilePath);
}


public static void main(String[] args) {
    try {
        cutOffXmlByXpath("//Part[@identifier != 'ID Page. Interview and Profile Form' and @identifier != 'Reports']", FILE_PATH, OUTPUT_FILE_PATH);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

The declaration above the xml is such :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-16"?>
```

Which is why I am reading the bytes from the file in **UTF-16** in the **getDataFromFile()** method. Otherwise, the code throws **an exception stating that that it cannot switch to encoding UTF-16.**

Now the code above throws the following exception :

```
java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException
at java.io.FileOutputStream.writeBytes(Native Method)
at java.io.FileOutputStream.write(FileOutputStream.java:345)
at com.ximpleware.XMLModifier.output(XMLModifier.java:2068)
at com.ximpleware.XMLModifier.output(XMLModifier.java:2193)
at Main.cutOffXmlByXpath(Main.java:111)
at Main.main(Main.java:161)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
at com.intellij.rt.execution.application.AppMain.main(AppMain.java:134)
```

If I change the encoding of the file to **UTF-8** and modify the **getDataFromFile()** method accordingly (that is, we read bytes from the file **without specifying any encoding** or **UTF-8 as encoding**) everything works fine.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Can you post a simplified version of XML file with that encoding header?

Comment: Thank you for your prompt response. I have uploaded a file [here](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B6soN-_-NHx6VHhFUWJhMF9pcFE/view) using which I have been able to reproduce the exception. The file is utf-16 encoded and I have modified the getDataFromFile() method accordingly(that is, to read raw bytes only without specifying any encoding) to pass to vtd-xml.

Comment: Can you send this XML file or better the entire test case  to me via email to jzhang@ximpleware.com?

Comment: @vtd-xml-author I have sent you the file. Please let me know when you have taken a look at the issue.

Comment: I will get back to you asap...

Comment: I check your xml file again, it is not utf-16 encoded at all, it is instead utf-8 encoded...

Comment: I didn't notice the parseFile() method before. That's definitely a lot better. About the encoding of the file, if I run this on linux, `file -i utf-16.xml` I get the result : `utf-16.xml: application/xml; charset=utf-16be`. Am I making any mistake?

Comment: I have tried on your update utf-16.xml on my computer and do not experience said exceptions... can you download the latest 2.12 and give it a spin on your end?

Comment: Yes, sure. I will do that and get back to you.

Comment: Saad, any updates?

Comment: Sorry, that I couldn't get back earlier. Seems like vtd-xml 2.12 is not available on maven. I have downloaded it from here https://sourceforge.net/projects/vtd-xml/?source=typ_redirect But I am not getting the XMLModifer here.

Answer (score 0):

I loaded everything on my end into eclipse. The first byte I got is -17, it is 0xef in binary, which is an invalid BOM starting byte. FYI, BOM should be 0xff 0xfe, or 0xfe 0xff... so it fails me in the parsing routine...

```
private static byte[] getDataFromFile(String filePath) throws IOException {
        File file = new File(filePath);
        FileInputStream fileInputStream = new FileInputStream(file);
        byte[] byteArray = new byte[(int) file.length()];
        //byteArray[0]=(byte)0xff;
        //byteArray[1]=(byte)0xfe;
        //byteArray[2]=0x00;

        fileInputStream.read(byteArray);

        System.out.println(" first byte "+byteArray[0]);
        System.out.println(" second byte "+byteArray[1]);
        System.out.println(" third byte "+byteArray[2]);
        System.out.println(" length "+file.length());
        return byteArray;
    }
```

the exception log looks like:

```
 first byte -17
 second byte -69
 third byte -65
 length 192
com.ximpleware.ParseException: XML decl error: Can't switch encoding to UTF-16
Line Number: 1 Offset: 39
    at com.ximpleware.VTDGen.matchUTFEncoding(VTDGen.java:2241)
    at com.ximpleware.VTDGen.process_dec_attr(VTDGen.java:3385)
    at com.ximpleware.VTDGen.parse(VTDGen.java:2632)
    at DOMTest.removeNode.cutOffXmlByXpath(removeNode.java:28)
    at DOMTest.removeNode.main(removeNode.java:46)
```

Comment: Yes, You are getting the exact same error. I am using 2.11. And I am also using the same file. Thanks.

Comment: Sorry, my mistake. Please modify the getDataFromFile() method like this to reproduce the exception.  `private static byte[] getDataFromFile(String filePath) throws IOException {
        File file = new File(filePath);
        FileInputStream fileInputStream = new FileInputStream(file);
        byte[] byteArray = new byte[(int) file.length()];
        fileInputStream.read(byteArray);
        return byteArray;
    }`

Comment: I am getting the first byte to be -2 if I print the 0th index of the byte array. Any clue?

Comment: how big is your file? 192 bytes long? I printed the first three bytes and the length of the file... and can you verify the file you sent me or resent the file?

Comment: I have sent you the file again. The file should be 380 bytes long. I am getting the first three bytes to be -2, -1 and 0. Let me know what you find. Thanks.